# Python - Optimal code to find preceding and following five words from a given point in a line

Tags: python, search, string

I'm trying to write code to find the 5 words on either side of a particular phrase. Easy enough, but I have to do this on a massive volume of data, thus the code needs to be optimal!

```
for file in listing:
    file2 = open('//home/user/Documents/Corpus/Files/'+file,'r')
    for line in file2:
        linetrigrams = trigram_split(line)
        for trigram in linetrigrams:
            if trigram in trigrams:
                line2 = line.replace(trigram,'###').split('###')
                window = (line2[0].split()[-5:] + line2[1].split()[:5])
                for item in window:
                    if item in mostfreq:
                        matrix[trigram][mostfreq[item]] += 1
```

Any suggestions for doing this much faster? It might be that I'm working with entirely the wrong data structures here. trigram_split() just gives all trigrams from the line (which are the units I need to create vectors for). 'Trigrams' is basically a list of about a million trigrams that I'm concerned with creating vectors for. Window gets the 5 words preceding and following the trigram (if that trigram is in the list), and then checks to see if they're in the list MostFreq (which is a dictionary of 1000 words as keys, each corresponding to an integer [0-100] as the stored value). This is then used to update the Matrix (which is a dictionary with lists ([0] * 1000) as the stored values). The corresponding value in the pseudo-matrix is incremented this way.

Comment: Is it possible for the 5 words before or after the phrase to span multiple lines, kind of like a sentence can span multiple lines in a book?  In this case, you would need to search the file as a whole and not just line by line.

Comment: Edited post for better clarity as to what I'm attempting

Comment: A) That sounds pretty complicated. I'm pretty sure I don't understand your revised post.   B) It sounds like you have working code.    Therefore C) Profile it! Run it with `python -m cProfile -o yourscript.profile yourscript.py arg1 arg2` and analyze the profile out. I like [gprof2dot](http://code.google.com/p/jrfonseca/wiki/Gprof2Dot) for a first cut myself.

Comment: your code is burning my eyes!!  I would recommend reading PEP8 -- http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/ - and using those standards.  Makes code easier to read, and the code formatting will work.

Comment: Your algorithm will fail if a trigram exists more than once per line, or if there are less than 5 words preceding or following the trigram.  Also, you say that MostFreq is a 1000 item dictionary with keys 0-100; that isn't possible.  You also say that Matrix is a dictionary with lists as the keys, that's not possible either.

Comment: @Brendan Some of that stuff just isn't true! MostFreq has 1000 keys and the items are 0-1000. The keys are used to say which slots in a given vector of the matrix correspond to which items in MostFreq, based on vector slot position. The algorithm doesn't fail in the situations you outline, actually. Also, Matrix is in fact a dictionary where each trigram is the key and the lists are the stored items. Woops, I see where I worded things wrong. Editing. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Several significant factors to consider when weighing various approaches:

- Multiline vs single line
- Length of the lines
- Length of the search pattern
- Rate of the search matching
- What to do if there are fewer than 5 words before/after
- How to handle non-word, non-space characters (newlines and punctuation)
- Case insensitive?
- What to do with overlapping matches? eg If the text is `We are the knights who say NI! NI NI NI NI NI NI NI NI` and you search for `NI` what do you return? Will this happen to you?
- What if `###` is in your data?
- Would you rather miss some, or return extra wrong results? There may be some tradeoffs, particularly with messy real world data.

You could try a regular expression...

```
import re
zen = """Beautiful is better than ugly. \
Explicit is better than implicit. \
Simple is better than complex. \
Complex is better than complicated. \
Flat is better than nested. \
Sparse is better than dense. \
Readability counts. \
Special cases aren't special enough to break the rules. \
Although practicality beats purity. \
Errors should never pass silently. \
Unless explicitly silenced. \
In the face of ambiguity, refuse the temptation to guess. \
There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it. \
Although that way may not be obvious at first unless you're Dutch. \
Now is better than never. \
Although never is often better than *right* now. \
If the implementation is hard to explain, it's a bad idea. \
If the implementation is easy to explain, it may be a good idea. \
Namespaces are one honking great idea -- let's do more of those!"""

searchvar = 'Dutch'
dutchre = re.compile(r"""((?:\S+\s*){,5})(%s)((?:\S+\s*){,5})""" % searchvar, re.IGNORECASE | re.MULTILINE)
print dutchre.findall(zen)
#[("obvious at first unless you're ", 'Dutch', '. Now is better than ')]
```

Alternate approach, which leads to worse results IMO...

```
def splitAndFind(text, phrase):
    text2 = text.replace(phrase, "###").split("###")
    if len(text2) > 1:
        return ((text2[0].split()[-5:], text2[1].split()[:5]))
print splitAndFind(zen, 'Dutch')
#(['obvious', 'at', 'first', 'unless', "you're"],
# ['.', 'Now', 'is', 'better', 'than'])
```

In iPython you can time it easily:

```
timeit dutchre.findall(zen)
1000 loops, best of 3: 814 us per loop

timeit 'Dutch' in zen
1000000 loops, best of 3: 650 ns per loop

timeit zen.find('Dutch')
1000000 loops, best of 3: 812 ns per loop

timeit splitAndFind(zen, 'Dutch')
10000 loops, best of 3: 18.8 us per loop
```

Comment: Btw, when developing python regular expressions I find re-try/retest super useful: http://re-try.appspot.com/

Comment: Ah, cool.  I've been using Rubular, which is in Ruby, but it's close enough that it works for most regex's, but a python one is much cooler.  http://www.rubular.com/

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [re](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html) module

```
import re

f = open('filepath', 'r')
txt = f.read()
# 'hey' is the search phrase
phrase = 'hey'
matches = re.findall(r'(\w+\s+\w+\s+\w+\s+\w+\s+\w+)\s+%s\s+(\w+\s+\w+\s+\w+\s+\w+\s+\w+)' % phrase, txt)
```

That should give you all the matches for the file.  You would need to os.walk to get all the files.

Comment: Thanks! Is there any way to replace 'hey' with a string variable?

Comment: Also, it's worth noting that the above example assumes "words" only contain letters numbers and underscores and that "words" will only be separated by whitespace.  Depending on the type of text you're searching, words may contain other characters like apostrophes or quotations, and they may be separated by more than just whitespace, like commas and periods.  I'd recommending just learning regular expressions and changing the regex query to suit your needs.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, massic data would be stored in files; loading such files in memory only to search them might slow your search down - so search the file on disk. However, for looking up the 5 words preceeding the phrase you will need random access, be aware of that.

As for searching, the [Boyer–Moore string search algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_string_search_algorithm) is usually faster than the naive approach. If you are working on random access files, this also may avoid the need to read the whole file into memory.

Especially if your phrase changes often but the data doesn't, then consider using some full text search engine as in [Full text search engine for Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4297672/full-text-search-engine-for-python) - however, this is likely to be overkill for this sort of homework assignment.

Answer (score 1):

I tried this script on a 18MB file:

```
for line in f:
    if phrase in line:
        line2 = line.replace(phrase,'###').split('###')
        result.append(line2[0].split()[-5:] + line2[1].split()[:5])
```

Elapsed time: `1.12602651429 s`

Answer (score 0):

If speed was really important I'd write a [python C extension module](http://docs.python.org/extending/) to do the hard work. This can give huge speed improvements.